# Detect routes and entities from Symfony2 vendor

Tags: symfony, routes, bundle, entities

i'm creating a bundle that adds an entity and a few routes to be use in a Symfony2 application.

I want my bundle to be used as a vendor, so I've created all the files, published it on GitHub and packagist and everything works fine.

My problem is now when I require the bundle in another project, my entities and my routes are not detected:

1) `php app/console doctrine:schema:update` doesn't detect any modification

2) When I try to hit a GET route from the vendor, here is the error I get:

`No route found for "GET ..."`

Any idea is welcome, what's the process to really do these things in a bundle?

Cheers.

Cyril

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the installation steps of the FOSUserBundle for example. Everyone who uses your published bundle, have to activate it in the appkernel and import the routes. For the entity I think the bundle user have also to subclass the entity.

Comment: First time creating a vendor bundle, forgot to include it in the AppKernel. The entity is automatically detected after that. Thanks!